# Android - Http Get Request

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to Get Request with code below but the stringbuilder is always null. The url is correct...

http://pastebin.com/mASvGmkq

EDIT

```
public static StringBuilder sendHttpGet(String url) {

    HttpClient http = new DefaultHttpClient();
    StringBuilder buffer = null;

    try {
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse resp = http.execute(get);
        buffer = inputStreamToString(resp.getEntity().getContent());
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        debug("ERRO EM GET HTTP URL:\n" + url + "\n" + e);
        return null;
    }

    debug("GET HTTP URL OK:\n" + buffer);
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: It is hard to guess the problem without seeing the code for Utils.sendHttpGet.

Comment: low quality of the question I would guess.

Comment: As stated above, the code for Utils.sendHttpGet was not posted, yet the question is essentially asking why the return value from that method is null.

Comment: post just the relevant snippet of code in the post and like to the full code. that makes for a better question

Comment: all the method is relevant for thsi question...is the method that request the http.....

Comment: Try this HTTP Client: http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

Comment: @ClaudioFernandes - I saw your edit and added an up-vote several minutes ago.

Comment: @ClaudioFernandes `buffer` is set from the function `inputStreamToString()` Is that a function you wrote? If so that needs to be included. Also, you'll get `null` if you have an exception. Is that occuring?

Comment: Why are you using a StringBuilder-object? You don't want to alter the response in your sendHttpGet()-method. I recommend you to use a String-object here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I usually do it like this:

```
try {
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    output = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
}
```

where `output` is a String-object.

Comment: got UnknownHostException

Comment: how does your `url` look like?