# implement nested restful services(heirarchical structure) in JAVA

Tags: rest, rest-client

I have 3 RESTful services serviceA,serviceB,serviceB. if serviceA has to call serviceB and serviceC, do i have to create clients for them and call them?how do i do that ?I am confused about how that would work..please help(in JAVA)

Answer (score 0):

Each service has to perform a http-get (or put/post/delete) on resource that is on a different REST-service. Thats all.
Of course you will have to implement a method that does the execution and handling of the results, and this very method will have to implement a HttpClient.

Comment: can you please give an example of how to do that?

Comment: something like my answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404598/android-http-get-request/14404699#14404699